# Google App Script - Calendar Update Trigger Firing 4 Times

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, eventtrigger

Goal: When a secondary calendar event(s) in Google Workspace 1 is updated (new, edit, delete), update the primary calendar in Google Workspace 1 to add new, edit existing, or delete existing event(s).

Note: the secondary calendar in Google Workspace 1 is shared from Google Workspace 2. So the actual update to an event occurs in a secondary calendar in Google Workspace 2 but is almost immediately reflected as an update in the secondary calendar in Google Workspace 1.

Result: This is working as intended when run manually.

Issue: When a trigger is added manually that runs when the calendar is updated (not time-based), the trigger fires four concurrent executions of the script. This duplicates the calendar event four times on the secondary calendar in Google Workspace 1.

Attempted Resolve: I put a lock service in place. This does prevent the calendar event duplication. However, this causes three of the four executions to fail. This results in 3 emails being sent to me, one email for each time the script fails.

Question: How can I only allow this script to run once? I think the simple answer is to just put in an if/else that if locked, terminate script. I have looked and cannot find examples of how this would be coded.

See code and screenshots below.

````
function calEventUpdate(){
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
      lock.waitLock(15000);
     
     //code here 
    
    var id="e48a0bmth3sn787dotb4n2rtjs@group.calendar.google.com"; // CHANGE - id of the secondary calendar to pull events from (Anduin Out)
    
      var today=new Date();
      var enddate=new Date();
      enddate.setDate(today.getDate()+7); // how many days in advance to monitor and block off time
      
      var secondaryCal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
      var secondaryEvents=secondaryCal.getEvents(today,enddate);
    
    
      var primaryCal=CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
      var primaryEvents=primaryCal.getEvents(today,enddate); // all primary calendar events
      
      var primaryEventTitle="Busy"; // update this to the text you'd like to appear in the new events created in primary calendar
      
      var stat=1;
      var evi, existingEvent; 
      var primaryEventsFiltered = []; // to contain primary calendar events that were previously created from secondary calendar
      var primaryEventsUpdated = []; // to contain primary calendar events that were updated from secondary calendar
      var primaryEventsCreated = []; // to contain primary calendar events that were created from secondary calendar
      var primaryEventsDeleted = []; // to contain primary calendar events previously created that have been deleted from secondary calendar
    
      Logger.log('Number of primaryEvents: ' + primaryEvents.length);  
      Logger.log('Number of secondaryEvents: ' + secondaryEvents.length);
      
      // create filtered list of existing primary calendar events that were previously created from the secondary calendar
      for (pev in primaryEvents)
      {
        var pEvent = primaryEvents[pev];
        if (pEvent.getTitle() == primaryEventTitle)
        { primaryEventsFiltered.push(pEvent); }
      }
    
      // process all events in secondary calendar
      for (sev in secondaryEvents)
      {
        stat=1;
        evi=secondaryEvents[sev];
        Utilities.sleep(1000); // added to prevent "too many updates" error on a busy calendar
        // if the secondary event has already been blocked in the primary calendar, update it
        for (existingEvent in primaryEventsFiltered)
          {
            var pEvent = primaryEventsFiltered[existingEvent];
            var secondaryTitle = evi.getTitle();
            var secondaryDesc = evi.getDescription();
            if ((pEvent.getStartTime().getTime()==evi.getStartTime().getTime()) && (pEvent.getEndTime().getTime()==evi.getEndTime().getTime()))
            {
              stat=0;
              pEvent.setTitle(primaryEventTitle);
              //pEvent.setDescription(secondaryTitle + '\n\n' + secondaryDesc);
              // event.setDescription(evi.getTitle() + '\n\n' + evi.getDescription());
              pEvent.setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PRIVATE); // set blocked time as private appointments in work calendar
              pEvent.setColor('9');
              primaryEventsUpdated.push(pEvent.getId());
              Logger.log('PRIMARY EVENT UPDATED'
                         + '\nprimaryId: ' + pEvent.getId() + ' \nprimaryTitle: ' + pEvent.getTitle() + ' \nprimaryDesc: ' + pEvent.getDescription());
            } 
          }
    
        if (stat==0) continue;    
        
        var d = evi.getStartTime();
        var n = d.getDay();
    
        if (evi.isAllDayEvent())
        {
          continue; // Do nothing if the event is an all-day or multi-day event. This script only syncs hour-based events
        }
        else if (n==1 || n==2 || n==3 || n==4 || n==5) // skip weekends. Delete this if you want to include weekends
        // if the secondary event does not exist in the primary calendar, create it
        {
          var newEvent = primaryCal.createEvent(primaryEventTitle,evi.getStartTime(),evi.getEndTime()); // change the Booked text to whatever you would like your merged event titles to be
          // alternative version below that copies the exact secondary event information into the primary calendar event
          // var newEvent = primaryCal.createEvent(evi.getTitle(),evi.getStartTime(),evi.getEndTime(), {location: evi.getLocation(), description: evi.getDescription()});  
          //newEvent.setDescription(evi.getTitle() + '\n\n' + evi.getDescription());
          newEvent.setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PRIVATE); // set blocked time as private appointments in work calendar
          newEvent.setColor('9');
          newEvent.removeAllReminders(); // so you don't get double notifications. Delete this if you want to keep the default reminders for your newly created primary calendar events
          primaryEventsCreated.push(newEvent.getId());
          Logger.log('PRIMARY EVENT CREATED'
                     + '\nprimaryId: ' + newEvent.getId() + '\nprimaryTitle: ' + newEvent.getTitle() + '\nprimaryDesc ' + newEvent.getDescription() + '\n');
        }
      }
    
      // if a primary event previously created no longer exists in the secondary calendar, delete it
      for (pev in primaryEventsFiltered)
      {
        var pevIsUpdatedIndex = primaryEventsUpdated.indexOf(primaryEventsFiltered[pev].getId());
        if (pevIsUpdatedIndex == -1)
        { 
          var pevIdToDelete = primaryEventsFiltered[pev].getId();
          Logger.log(pevIdToDelete + ' deleted');
          primaryEventsDeleted.push(pevIdToDelete);
          primaryEventsFiltered[pev].deleteEvent();
        }
      }  
    
      Logger.log('Primary events previously created: ' + primaryEventsFiltered.length);
      Logger.log('Primary events updated: ' + primaryEventsUpdated.length);
      Logger.log('Primary events deleted: ' + primaryEventsDeleted.length);
      Logger.log('Primary events created: ' + primaryEventsCreated.length);
    
      lock.releaseLock();
    }```

[Simultaneous script executions][1]
[Trigger][2]
[Trigger Settings][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcbJU.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6giq.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG93W.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

#### This might be a bug:

The behavior you're describing ([EventUpdateTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#eventupdatetrigger) -as well as [EventOpenTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#eventopentrigger) firing multiple times) might be a bug, and is currently being investigated on Google Issue Tracker:

- [EventOpenTrigger is fired several times when trying to add a guest.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172947241)

Please consider [starring the referenced issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it.

#### Workaround:

As [doubleunary mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69697213), use [Lock.hasLock()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#hasLock()) to avoid successive trigger executions causing the event to be duplicated multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if another script instance currently has a lock through [Lock.hasLock()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#hasLock()).

Note that this method is not always the best possible way to avoid conflicts, as there is no way to tell whether the lock was acquired during an update of the *same event* or *another event* that just happened to fire a trigger at the same time — as [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events) tells, *"triggers do not tell you which event changed or how it changed.*"

You may want to study [Google Calendar events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events) carefully to determine how to synchronize calendars.

Alternatively, [share the calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082) instead of attempting synchronization.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this approach.